# Is it possible to link existing Google AdWords account via API?

Tags: java, google-ads-api

I'd like to implement functionality of linking existing account(using only client id) to my MCC in my java application (this functionality is available with google adwords site). Is it possible? How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this functionality isn't exposed in the API.

Comment: Are there any plans to introduce this feature in the api?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to link Adwords Account to MCC via Adwords API.

Use [mutateLink](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201802/ManagedCustomerService#mutateLink) API from `ManagedCustomerService` in Adwords API.

Required params for the same

managerCustomerId - *The manager customer ID in link.*

clientCustomerId - *The client customer ID in this link.*